# How can I make my Mac automatically switch to a new speaker when it is connected, and back to my internal speakers after it's disconnected?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

For some reason, when I connect my Sony Bluetooth speaker to my Mac, my Mac usually does not automatically set this Bluetooth speaker as my audio output device. Audio continues playing from my internal speakers until I manually click the audio icon in the menu bar and set "SRS-XB12" as my output device.

Furthermore, when I disconnect this speaker, my Mac sets the audio output device to my USB Microphone, rather than back to my internal speakers.

When I connect my Bluetooth speaker, I want my Mac to automatically start playing audio from that speaker. When I disconnect my speaker, I want it to play audio from the internal speakers. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

After spending far too many hours trying to find the root cause of why this was happening, I gave up and wrote a shell script.

First, we need a way to find and change audio devices from the command line. Luckily, developer Deweller made a small utility to do exactly that: https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx. It can be installed via Homebrew or MacPorts if you have either installed; alternately, download the [Intel](http://packages.macports.org/switchaudio-osx/switchaudio-osx-1.0.0_0.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2) or [Apple Silicon](http://packages.macports.org/switchaudio-osx/switchaudio-osx-1.0.0_0.darwin_20.arm64.tbz2) binary from MacPorts directly, and copy `switchaudiosource` into `/usr/local/bin`; it should work as-is with no dependencies.

I wrote the following script. You'll want to edit the names of `speakerA` and `SpeakerB`.

```
#!/bin/sh

while sleep 2
do
    speakerA="SRS-XB12"
    speakerB="Built-in Output"

    switchAndRewind() {
        echo $1 > /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt
        if [ "$(switchaudiosource -c)" != "$2" ]
        then
            for device in {output,system}
            do
                    SwitchAudioSource -t "$device" -s "$2"
            done
            osascript -e 'if application "QuickTime Player" is not running then return' -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player"' -e 'repeat with i from 1 to count of every document' -e 'if document i is playing and duration of document i > 0 then set current time of document i to (current time of document i) - 2' -e 'end repeat' -e 'end tell'
        fi
    }

    if ! cat /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt
    then
        switchaudiosource -a | grep $speakerA && echo "connected" > /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt || echo "disconnected" > /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt
    elif [ "$(cat /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt)" == "disconnected" ] && switchaudiosource -a | grep $speakerA
    then
        switchAndRewind "connected" "$speakerA"
    elif [ "$(cat /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt)" == "connected" ] && ! switchaudiosource -a | grep $speakerA
    then
        switchAndRewind "disconnected" "$speakerB"
    fi
done
```

This script does the following every 2 seconds:

- If it doesn't already exist, create a temporary text file which records whether `speakerA` is connected to the Mac.
- If `speakerA` was previously disconnected, and is now connected, switch to `speakerA`.
- If `speakerA` was previously connected, and is now disconnected, switch to `SpeakerB` (my internal speakers).
- In either of the above two cases, we also update the temporary file, so the code will only run once per connection or disconnection. And, if Quicktime is currently playing any audio, we'll rewind the file a few seconds so I don't miss anything as devices are switching.

In order for this script to be useful, I needed it to start automatically, so I made a LaunchAgent. I decided I wanted this to live as a single, self-contained file, so I put all the code on one (unreadable) line and dumped it directly into my LaunchAgent plist. Note that because LaunchAgents need to know the full path to most binaries, this LaunchAgent assumes that the `switchaudiosource` binary lives in `/usr/local/bin/`.

```
<!--

Changes audio output device to "SRS-XB12" when a device by that name is connected; changes audio output device back to "Built-in Output" when a device named "SRS-XB12" is disconnected. Edit these names to whatever is appropriate for your sound setup.

Requires SwitchAudioSource to be present in /usr/local/bin/

-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>wowfunhappy.audio-switcher</string>

        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/bin/sh</string>
            <string>-c</string>
            <string>while sleep 2; do speakerA="SRS-XB12" ; speakerB="Built-in Output" ; switchAndRewind() { echo $1 > /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt ; if [ "$(/usr/local/bin/switchaudiosource -c)" != "$2" ] ; then for device in {output,system} ; do /usr/local/bin/SwitchAudioSource -t "$device" -s "$2" ; done ; osascript -e 'if application "QuickTime Player" is not running then return' -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player"' -e 'repeat with i from 1 to count of every document' -e 'if document i is playing and duration of document i > 0 then set current time of document i to (current time of document i) - 5' -e 'end repeat' -e 'end tell' ; fi ; } ; if ! cat /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt ; then /usr/local/bin/switchaudiosource -a | grep $speakerA &amp;&amp; echo "connected" > /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt || echo "disconnected" > /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt ; elif [ "$(cat /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt)" == "disconnected" ] &amp;&amp; /usr/local/bin/switchaudiosource -a | grep $speakerA ; then switchAndRewind "connected" "$speakerA" ; elif [ "$(cat /tmp/audioSwitcherSavedState.txt)" == "connected" ] &amp;&amp; ! /usr/local/bin/switchaudiosource -a | grep $speakerA ; then switchAndRewind "disconnected" "$speakerB" ; fi ; done</string>
        </array>

        <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
        <array>
            <string>Aqua</string>
        </array>

        <key>ProcessType</key>
        <string>Background</string>

        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>

        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>

    </dict>
</plist>
```

Save the above as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/wowfunhappy.audio-switcher.plist` and log out and back in, and audio should switch automatically.

Comment: For such a sort time interval, would it not be more efficient to keep the same script running and just `sleep` between iterations?  After all, the interval doesn't need to be precise. And shell startup isn't free (especially for a heavyweight shell such as bash), and will run all the startup scripts &c every time.

Comment: @gidds Good point, I will look at that! I should also probably switch to `sh` now that you mention it.

Comment: @gidds Yes, that actually is noticeably better—the audio switches more quickly even after I moved it from 1 down to 2 seconds! Thank you!

Comment: That's grossly horrifying! You might consider some more elegant solutions such as creating a background app that registers an audio object property listener, maybe something modeled off of [this](https://github.com/yonilevy/automute). Or at the very least set the launchagent to only run on bluetooth connection changes, which you can do hackily by watchpath of com.apple.bluetooth.plist or more elegantly by using undocument launchd launchevents on iokit bluetooth

Comment: @1110101001 Thanks for the automute link, I'll take a look. I absolutely agree my current solution is gross, but it's where I arrived after many months of frustration; it works reliably and and uses < 0.01% CPU. Watching com.apple.bluetooth.plist doesn't work consistently, and while I did try several iokit Bluetooth launchevents, nothing seemed to fire at the right time.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Hmm the iokit bluetooth launchevents would probably be the easiest way. What do you mean by they didn't fire consistently for you?

Comment: Fyi found another method of listening to IOKit events. You can use `IOServiceAddMatchingNotification to listen to changes in IOKit driver hierarchy. Maybe you can explore with this.

Comment: @1110101001 In my particular case, the speaker doesn't seem to be sending the proper IO events. At this point, I'm legitimately convinced I've stumbled across some kind of low-level bug in the firmware of most Bluetooth speakers, which is triggered by the fact that I use VirtualHere to share my Mac's Bluetooth adapter with a secondary PC. I've had five speakers from different companies spontaneously stop switching audio automatically with _any_ Apple host device, after I used them for a few months with my Mac. They worked fine out of the box, then stopped, and factory resets don't help.

Comment: @1110101001 But—as always, thank you so much! I really appreciate your insight into low-level Mac stuff, it's hard to find especially for older systems.

Comment: " the speaker doesn't seem to be sending the proper IO events" – Have you inspected using `IORegistryExplorer` (available as part of xcode developer tools)? If the speaker is available as an output source, then surely there must be some state change.

Comment: Ah, yes, there is a state change ofc, it's just not sending the Bluetooth connected or disconnected events... maybe I can work with this... 